# How to initialize SQLite connection

Tags: flutter, dart

I new in Flutter.
I have already exist db and need add it to app.
Put file in assets/db/sms.db 
in file pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
    - assets/db/sms.db
```

Copy db file in applicationDirectory.
In file categoriesList.dart I try connect to it.
SmsDataBaseHelper.instance.getAllCategories()
I get error message.

[image]

database_helper.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import '/models/categories.dart';


class SmsDataBaseHelper {
    static final SmsDataBaseHelper instance = SmsDataBaseHelper._();
    static Database? _db;
    
    SmsDataBaseHelper._();
    
    Future<Database> get db async {
        _db  ??= await _init();
        return _db!;
    }
    
    Future<Database> _init() async {
        io.Directory applicationDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String dbPathSms =  path.join(applicationDirectory.path, "sms.db");
        bool dbExistsSms = await io.File(dbPathSms).exists();
        if (!dbExistsSms) {
          // Copy from asset
          ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path.join("assets", "db", "sms.db"));
          List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
          // Write and flush the bytes written
          await io.File(dbPathSms).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
        }
        return await openDatabase(dbPathSms);
    }

    /// get all the words from categories
    Future<List<Categories>> getAllCategories() async {
        if (_db == null) {
          throw "_db is not initiated, initiate using [init(db)] function";
        }
        List<Map>? categories;

        await _db!.transaction((txn) async {
          categories = await txn.query(
            "categories",
            columns: [
              "name",
              "ru",
            ],
          );
        });

        return categories!.map((e) => Categories.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();
    }
}
```

categoriesList.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import '../utils/database_helper.dart';
import '../models/categories.dart';


class CategoriesList extends StatefulWidget {
    const CategoriesList({super.key});

    @override
    State<CategoriesList> createState() => _CategoriesListState();
}

class _CategoriesListState extends State<CategoriesList> {
  //late List<Categories> categoriesList;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('SMS Home Page'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder<List<Categories>>(
                future: SmsDataBaseHelper.instance.getAllCategories(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Categories>> snapshot) {
                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.none:
                            return const Text('start widget');
                        case ConnectionState.active:
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                            return const Text('Awaiting result from api...');
                        case ConnectionState.done:
                            if (snapshot.hasError)
                                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                            return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
                    }
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this class to build database ..

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
```

import 'package:path/path.dart';

```
class SqlDb {
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database?> get db async {
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = await initialDb();
      return _db;
    } else {
      return _db;
    }
  }

  initialDb() async {
    String databasepath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasepath, 'shop.db');
    Database mydb = await openDatabase(path,
        onCreate: _onCreate, version: 1, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
    return mydb;
  }

  _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldversion, int newversion) async {}

  deletemydatabase() async {
    String databasepath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasepath, 'shop.db');
    var x = await deleteDatabase(path);
    return x;
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE cart (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , title TEXT, size TEXT , code TEXT , img TEXT , price TEXT )");
  }

//Select
  readData(String sql) async {
    Database? mydb = await db;
    List<Map> response = await mydb!.rawQuery(sql);
    return response;
  }
  //insert data

  insertData(String sql) async {
    Database? mydb = await db;
    int response = await mydb!.rawInsert(sql);
    return response;
  }

  deleteData(String sql) async {
    Database? mydb = await db;
    int response = await mydb!.rawDelete(sql);
    return response;
  }

  updateData(String sql) async {
    Database? mydb = await db;
    int response = await mydb!.rawUpdate(sql);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to add db name to pubspec.yaml